# Unable to apply CU 13 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am running version 10.50.4033 and would like to apply cumulative update 14.  However, I get an error that basically says I'm not at the correct version to apply this patch.

I assume I have to remove patch MS14-044 to apply CU13, but I'd like to get some confirmation before I go through all of that work.

[SQL Build numbers](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)